# Laravel 5.4 Polymorphic relationship not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, polymorphism

Currently trying to get a Polymorphic relationship working in Laravel 5.4.

I am trying to dump the json of all "parent objects" (mappings) in a table with these few lines:

```
$mappings = Mapping::all();
return $mappings->toJson();
```

However, the call to `$this->mappingable` just returns `NULL`. Even when accessing a single model using this:

```
$mapping = Mapping::find(1);
$title_mapping = $mapping->mappingable; //Still NULL
```

When looking at the queries made using Debugbar, I just see the following query: `select * from mappings where mappings.id = '1' limit 1`. This seems wrong, as the query should also get the info from the other tables, shouldn't it?

Source code for the models I am trying to do this with is below:

```
Relation::morphMap([
    'title' => 'App\TitleMapping',
    'year' => 'App\YearMapping',
]);

class Mapping extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mappings_mysql';
    //

    public function mappingable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        return array_merge($arr, $this->mappingable->toArray());
    }

}

class TitleMapping extends Model {
    protected $table = "title_mappings";

    protected $connection = 'mappings_mysql';

    public function mapping()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Mapping', 'mappingable', "mapping_type", "mapping_id"); //No difference between App\Mapping and App/Mapping
    }
}

class YearMapping extends Model {
    protected $table = "year_mappings";

    protected $connection = 'mappings_mysql';

    public function mapping()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Mapping', 'mappingable', "mapping_type", "mapping_id");
    }
}
```

Create syntaxes for the Table are shown below:

```
-- Create syntax for TABLE 'mappings'
CREATE TABLE `mappings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tmdbid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imdbid` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `report_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locked` tinyint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_reports` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mapping_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mapping_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'title_mappings'
CREATE TABLE `title_mappings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aka_title` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'year_mappings'
CREATE TABLE `year_mappings` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aka_year` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: maybe its null, how did you insert the mapping of id one?

Comment: @AmeerSalahAldeen I manually inserted some test data, but the id's match up after manual verification. (A Simple SQL join query also worked fine, but I would rather have to work this using eloquent)

Comment: could you please check if the mapping_type in the data base is  'title' or 'App\TitleMapping' and try both cases , maybe the problem is the namespace of the class

Comment: @AmeerSalahAldeen It is 'title'. Even if that were the case, it does not explain why Laravel won't even query the other table. From what I read, after the select statement, some join statements should follow.